# Get content by URI

Tags: java, servlets, get

I create a small java servlet and would like to map the content dynamically by the URI. For example if someone call following URI `http://example.com/yell/2013-08-01/first-article` my servlet should get the content by date and title from the database and response it to the client.

I not sure about the 'correct' pattern to implement this. My idea was to listen at  `<url-pattern>/yell/*</url-pattern>`, get the path with `request.getRequestURI(`) and splitt it at the `'/'` character. Is this the common pattern? What would you suggest? I guess REST is not the 'correct' way? A small example would be create. Thanks for you hints!

Comment: You might want to take a look at something like [urlrewritefilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) which means you could rewrite the url into query parameters.

Comment: why do you think REST is not the correct way? Rest will extract all of the fields you need for you

Comment: @boris-the-spider Thanks, looks very nice.

Comment: @mmohab I thought REST is defined with a kind of XML-Schema file and return a XML-Struct. I would like dynamically redirect and insert the content in a jsp. Can I use REST for this too? Maybe return JSON and display the content with JavaScript?

Comment: @hofmeister yes you can use rest with json or xml I will post a JEE example for rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other solution to use rest, you can use Spring or Java EE, If you choose Java EE, you need an application server that supports Java EE like glassfish, Apache tomcat doesn't support Java EE applications.

then you can follow a tutorial like this one:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

here is how your code may look like.

```
@Path("yell/{date}/{articleName}")
public class RestService {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getJson(@PathParam("date") String date, 
      @PathParam("articleName") String articleName) {
        return "{ \"content\" : \"// TODO\" }";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way with REST, but if the client has JavaScript disabled I cannot use it to render the result. Is it ok to redirect the client to a jsp and use REST only to recognize the content? I guess in that case I destroy the REST pattern, because no result is returned.

Comment: @hofmeister probably since Javascript is disabled, your best approach is to use servlets and JSP. use a servlet to extract parameters and use jsp to display the result

Comment: Yea, I did this. Just returned `Viewable`. Works great, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a particular reason to write the servlet by hand, then your approach should work. On the other hand, the [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) system, while requiring some additional setup to launch, makes this sort of task insanely easy: you just write a regular Java method that takes a `Date` and a `String` (or two `String`s), annotate it with `@RequestMapping`, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression to extract the date and the name of the article.

```
String regExp = "yell\\/(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\\/(.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = 
pattern.matcher("yell/2013-08-01/first-article");
if( matcher.matches() ){
    // date
    String date = matcher.group(1);
    // article name
    String articleName = matcher.group(2);
}
```